# What is the use of the script params of the _update endpoint in elasticsearch？Can performance be improved?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I believe it doesn't make sense to add script parameters to the _update endpoint.
First,if it is for dynamically passing in parameters instead of hard-coded parameters, it does not make sense, because no matter whether it is a java or a rest client, only the json string in the request body needs to be replaced, either in the `script.source` or in the `script.params`. It's the same wherever you use `script.params` .

such as this request

```
POST book/_update/1
{
   "script": {
     "source": "ctx._source.isbn=115"
   }
}
```

If you use the params in the script, it is written like this:

```
POST book/_update/1
{
   "script": {
     "source": "ctx._source.isbn=params.val1",
     "params": {
     "val1":115
     }
   }
}
```

Regardless of the difference between the two ways of writing the api in java, the final essence is to send an http request, even if there are no params in the script, only the way of writing 115 in the first way can be replaced with variables. If we talk about the benefits, it is just that the parameters can be passed as a map, and the api looks clearer:

```
     // Define the variable
     int updateValue = 115;

     // Prepare the script; use 'updateValue' as a parameter
     Script script = new Script(ScriptType. INLINE, "painless", "ctx._source. isbn = params. updateValue",
             Collections. singletonMap("updateValue", updateValue));

     //Create the UpdateRequest
     UpdateRequest request = new UpdateRequest(index, id)
             .script(script)
             .fetchSource(true)
             .versionType(VersionType. INTERNAL);

     // Perform the update request
     UpdateResponse response = client.update(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

That is to say, a `Collections.singletonMap("updateValue", updateValue)` can be passed here instead of `Script script = new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", "ctx._source.isbn = "+updateValue`, does it mean this is this The benefit of script.params? The api is clearer? But the first type cannot be truly hard-coded, because java can replace that 115

Secondly, in terms of performance, it seems that with script.params, the script is the same every time, and it is only compiled for the first time. If you want to change 115 to 116 or 117 in the future, you don’t need to recompile, but if you If you change 115 to 116 in script.source, there will be another recompilation process.

So I tested it and executed the following process for the first time:

```
DELETE book/_doc/1
PUT book/_doc/1
{
   "initd": "d"
}
POST book/_update/1
{
   "script": {
     "source": "ctx._source.isbn2=115"
   }
}
```

The last _update process took 274 ms
Then execute:

```
DELETE book/_doc/1
PUT book/_doc/1
{
   "initd": "d"
}
POST book/_update/1
{
   "script": {
     "source": "ctx._source.isbn2=116"
   }
}
```

The last _update process took 36 ms
That is to say, the first time is slow, and the second time is fast, even if the source changes

Then test the script.params way:

```
DELETE book/_doc/1
PUT book/_doc/1
{
   "initd": "d"
}
POST book/_update/1
{
   "script": {
     "source": "ctx._source.isbn=params.val1",
     "params": {
     "val1":120
     }
   }
}
```

_update takes 82ms, and then test the modified value:

```
DELETE book/_doc/1
PUT book/_doc/1
{
   "initd": "d"
}
POST book/_update/1
{
   "script": {
     "source": "ctx._source.isbn=params.val1",
     "params": {
     "val1":121
     }
   }
}
```

_update takes 17ms

The second time is also faster. It is said that even if script.params is not used, the second request will be faster and will not cause recompilation problems. That is to say, the method of script.params will not improve performance?
So what's the point of using script.params?

Comment: You cannot make performance assertions by comparing single invocations. You need to build a real load test case with multiple thousands of invocations and run it multiple times, you'll see that if the script source changes too often when doing thousand of invocations, you'll hit some walls. Now if your use case only involves a few update invocations from time to time, it is a non-issue for you and you'll see no impact.